# joomla using multiple database queries in one function

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

In certain functions I may need to do a couple of queries like so:

```
    $user = & JFactory::getUser();
    $db = & JFactory::getDBO();
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('id');
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__users'));
    $query->where('username='.$db->quote($response->username));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $user_id = $db->loadResult();

    if ($user_id == "") 
    {
           //do something
    }


    $query1  = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query1->select('app_id');
    $query1->from($db->quoteName('#__app_ids'));
    $query1->where('app_descr='.$db->quote($this->app_descr).' AND app_valid=TRUE');
    $db->setQuery($query1);
    $app_id = $db->loadResult();
```

I find if I don't change `query` to `query1` I can't get this to work for the subsequent queries. Outside of Joomla I've never had to do this as I close the mysql connection use the same variable as long as it is in the right order, all is well.

Two questions:

1. Is this right? Or is there a better way to do this?
2. Do I need to check for mysql failure of `loadResult`? How would I go about this. Looking at the Joomla core often I see nothing but sometimes there is a mix of things to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) It should work with the same variable name, since you are getting a new query object since your method parameter is set to `true`. Try calling `$query->clear();` just after getting query object

```
$query  = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->clear();
$query->select('app_id');
```

2) In Joomla 3 it should be something like

```
try
{
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $user_id = $db->loadResult();
}
catch (RuntimeException $e)
{
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

And in Joomla 2.5

```
if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
    JError::raiseWarning(500, $db->getErrorMsg());
}
```

Also, change

```
$user = & JFactory::getUser();
$db = & JFactory::getDBO();
```

to

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
```

Objects are returned by reference anyway in PHP 5, and it will throw a warning since php 5.3+

Comment: For #2, something like: `if (!$user_id) { throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());}`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, on Joomla *the JFactory::getDBO()* always returns the same instance of connection,(at the atual version today) so each time you set the SQL you, in true, are rewriting the previous SQL. In resume this code need multiple connections, and this way dont support, you will need to write your own version of JDatabaseDriver, maybe your own version of a global static array to control your own pool of mysqli connections. PHP is poor about pool connections, isn't as JAVA or .NET, to quick code you will need to think the logic and to try to use only one connection each time, one opened query each time, always think that the *JFactory::getDBO()* isn't thread safe, take care about this. You never can start one transaction inside one php without commit ou rollback, it causes problems on execution of other pages.